# Windows 10 - PowerShell registry drives are not working properly

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-registry

I am using Windows 10 20H2, I have successfully recreated this problem multiple times without failure, on PowerShell Desktop 5.1.19041.610 and PowerShell Core 7.1.1.

The problem: Test-Path only works with two PowerShell registry drives(shortened registry hive names):

`HKCU:` and `HKLM:`

They are abbreviations of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` respectively.

In PowerShell the full names of them are:

`Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` respectively.

However there are five registry hives, the other three being:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG` and `HKEY_USERS`

Their shortnames:

`HKCR:`, `HKCC:` and `HKU:`

`Test-Path` can't find the drives, however `Test-Path` can find them if full names are supplied:

```powershell
TEST-PATH HKCR:
TEST-PATH HKCU:
TEST-PATH HKLM:
TEST-PATH HKU:
TEST-PATH HKCC:
TEST-PATH REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
TEST-PATH REGISTRY::HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG
TEST-PATH REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS
$PSVersionTable
```

[image]

[image]

I am curious and I want to know why it behaves like this.

Can anyone offer an explanation?

I have confirmed the other three drives also don't work with other cmdlets, how can I use the three registry drives?

Comment: according to this page >>> Registry Provider - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_registry_provider?view=powershell-7.1 <<< the registry provider ONLY supports those two drives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are not created by default, but you can create them:

```
PS C:\>New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                               ---------------
HKCR                                   Registry      HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

PS C:\>Test-Path HKCR:
True
PS C:>
```

Comment: I have `HKCR:` defined in my profile (with the output piped to `Out-Null`). I then also create acorr3espoinding function for each Registry drive using the same definition found in the existing drive letter functions: `'HKcR:','HKCU:','HKLM:' | ForEach { 'Function {0} {{ Set-Location $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name }}' -f $_ | Invoke-Expression }`

Answer (score 2):

Yep, according to Microsoft Docs, PowerShell registry provider only provides two PSDrives by default:

`HKCU:` and `HKLM:`

They can be traversed like a filesystem.

To get all registry PSDrives:

```powershell
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry | Select-Object Name, Provider, Root
```

It will return something like this:

```powershell
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry | Select-Object Name, Provider, Root

Name Provider                           Root
---- --------                           ----
HKCU Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
```

```powershell
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -Name HKCR
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG -Name HKCC
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_USERS -Name HKU
```

These will create `PSDrives` for the other three hives:

```powershell
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry | Select-Object Name, Provider, Root

Name Provider                           Root
---- --------                           ----
HKCC Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG
HKCR Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
HKCU Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
HKU  Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry HKEY_USERS
```

`Test-Path`:

```powershell
PS C:\Windows\System32> Test-Path HKCC:
True
PS C:\Windows\System32> Test-Path HKCR:
True
PS C:\Windows\System32> Test-Path HKCU:
True
PS C:\Windows\System32> Test-Path HKLM:
True
PS C:\Windows\System32> Test-Path HKU:
True
PS C:\Windows\System32>
```